# Android: stop repeating images in listview, performance issue

Tags: android, android-adapter

i have an arrayaadapter where i am retrieving the phone contacts numbers with images
and displaying it in the list.

```
@Override 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 

    View view = convertView; 

    if (view == null) { 
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) (getContext() 
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)); 
    view = inflater.inflate(renderer, null); 
    } 


    TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name); 
    TextView textContNo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactno); 
    TextView textEmailId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailId); 
    Profile contact = listCont.get(position); 
    text.setText(contact.getName());    

    QuickContactBadge photo = (QuickContactBadge ) view.findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge1);  
    photo.setTag(contact.getMobileNo()); 
    new LoadImage(photo).execute(contact.getMobileNo());
```

and loading the images in backgroundthread using asyncTask

```
 class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{ 

        private QuickContactBadge qcb; 

        public LoadImage(QuickContactBadge qcb) { 
        this.qcb= qcb; 
        } 
        @Override 
        protected Bitmap doInBackground( final String... params) { 
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
        new QuickContactHelper(activity, qcb, (String) params[0]).addThumbnail(); 
        } 
        }); 
        return null; 
        } 
        @Override 
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) { 

        } 
        }
```

i face two problems , the images are repeating and scrolling is not smooth
iam trying to implemente viewholder in getview method but not sure how to use it or is there any other way to stop images from repeating. Any help is appreciated

Comment: your current code is working? if yes you are getting any error then post log also

Comment: yes my correct code is working..not getting errors but images are repeating and scroll is struckin

Comment: i have problem here why you are using AsyncTask because you are using runOnUiThread in doInBackground then code always executed on UI Thread

Comment: ohh is it...without that async is not working...what am i doing wrong?

Comment: depend on what you are doing in addThumbnail method post relevant code

Comment: ok this is my contacthelper class  http://pastebin.com/U8kGr9xS  which has the addthumbnail(0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load image efficiently, [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) is a good library to load images in background efficiently (Lazy Loading).

Some times what happen, when you are inflating any view first time, and scroll view, list has some limitation of repeating old views. The best solution to do is that you must use ViewHolder which holds your all views like

```
class ViewHolder
{
     View rowView;
     TextView textview = null;

     public ViewHolder(View view)
     {
          rowView = view;
     }

     public TextView getTextView()
     {
          if(textview ==null)
                textview = rowView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
          return textview;
     }
}
```

and you can use it in your adapter like,

```
if(convertview ==null)
{
    convertview = inflater.inflate(renderer, null);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(convertview);
    convertview.setTag(holder);
} 

ViewHolder tempHolder = (ViewHolder) convertview.getTag();

TextView textView = tempHolder.getTextView();
```

If you do this thing, your reference of `textview` and other views be hold in `ViewHolder`.

Comment: so should i make all my view to be view class and later call it

Comment: holder = new ViewHolder(view);

 holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name); 
 holder.textContNo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactno); 
 holder.textEmailId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailId); 
 view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder =(ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
  private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textEmailId;
  public TextView textContNo;
  public TextView text;
  
    }

Comment: Yes, this will let you create a good practice to work with adapters.

Comment: iam doinf as below but getting nullpointerexcetion on line 27  http://pastebin.com/2S06YUQU

Comment: hi if u dnt mind can u please tell me how to integrate the Universal Image Loader  library into my project

Comment: There is a tutorial how to use that library. http://www.intexsoft.com/blog/item/68-universal-image-loader-part-1.html

Answer (score 0):

I think librairy android-query is made for you
there in the documentation to help you: http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading

Comment: @letroll..no dude ..i has something to do with viewholder , binding the views

Comment: I also think you need to look to the WeakReference and use a cache system